# Find the point on the line 6x+5y+5=0 which is closest to the point (1,-5)

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I tried putting y alone and got y=(-6x-5)/5. Which I then put into the distance formula sqrt((x-1)^2+(y+5) and substitute the number above in for y but my answer never comes out correct.. Wondering if I could get some help.

Comment: If you draw a parpendicular from the point to the straight line the foot of the parpendicular is the point you require. Check this

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: [Distance from a point to a line.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

Answer (score 1):

**Method**$\#1:$

As the perpendicular distance is the shortest  find the equation of the perpendicular  of $$6x+5y+5=0$$ passing through $(1,-5)$

Find the intersection of the two lines.

**Method**$\#2:$

$$6x+5y+5=0\iff\dfrac x5=\dfrac{y+1}{-6}$$ $=k$(say)

$\implies x=\cdots, y=\cdots$

We need to minimize $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y+5)^2}$$

$\iff $  to minimize $$(x-1)^2+(y+5)^2$$ which will be quadratic in $k$

Do you know how to find the possible extreme values of a quadratic in real?

Comment: would you find the derivative of that equation? Plugging (-6x-5)/5 in for y?

Comment: @OcroDex, We don't need derivative. Also, replacing both $x,y$ with $k$ will leave for us easier calculation. Please let me know if you are stuck

Comment: I'm not sure you would go about replacing those.

Comment: @OcroDex, $x=5k,y=-1-6k$  We need to minimize $$f(k)=(5k-1)^2+(-6k-1+5)^2=41\left(k-\dfrac{29}{41}\right)^2+1^2+4^2-\dfrac{29^2}{41}$$  So, $f(k)$ will be minimum if?

Answer (score 1):

Another method. Take a circle centered in $(1,-5)$ that is
$$(x-1)^2+(y+5)^2=d^2$$
The slope of tangent line is
$$y'=-\dfrac{f_x}{f_y}=-\dfrac{x-1}{y+5}$$
will be $-\dfrac65$, the slope of given line. Then it's sufficient to solve the system
\begin{cases}
6x+5y+5=0,\\
5x-6y=35.
\end{cases}

Comment: Is this not similar to my method $\#1?$

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$\sqrt{(6^2+5^2)\left((x-1)^2+(y+5)^2\right)}\geq6(x-1)+5(y+5)=14.$$
Thus, $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y+5)^2}\geq\frac{14}{\sqrt{61}}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x-1,y+5)||(6,5),$ which gives the needed point.

I got $\left(\frac{145}{61},-\frac{235}{61}\right).$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:-**
$(1,-5)$ projected on the point $(x, \frac{-5-6x}{5})$. Line passes through $(0,-1)$. Vector joining points $(0,-1)$and $(x, \frac{-5-6x}{5})$ is perpendicular to the Vector joining  $(x, \frac{-5-6x}{5})$ to $(1,-5)$. Find $x$ from the condition.